# GLKit TextureLoader leak and allocation

Tags: ios, textures, glkit

I'm loading lots of texture (one at each frame update) with

`- (void)textureWithContentsOfData:(NSData *)data options:(NSDictionary *)textureOperations queue:(dispatch_queue_t)queue completionHandler:(GLKTextureLoaderCallback)block` method.
Some minutes later my app is crashing because I have a huge amount of allocation and leaks from -[GLKShaderBlockNode copywithZone:] .
I don't know how the solve this. On Apple deforms' they say that it's a GLKit bug. Did you tried to solve this leak and allocation problem ?